# Найти сумму четных элементов объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты, рекурсия

Помогите написать функцию, которая получает сумму всех четных элементов в объекте.

```
let data = {    
 country: 2,    
  size: [{    
      country: 4,    
      size: [{    
        country: 2,    
        size: [{    
          country: 1,    
        }]    
      }]    
    },    
    {    
      country: 3,    
      size: [{    
        country: 6,    
        size: [{    
          country: 5,    
        }]    
      }]    
    }   
  ]    
} ;
```

Мое решение:

```
function recursion(param, sum) {
  if (typeof param.size !== 'undefined') {
    sum = param.country
     console.log(param.size)
    return recursion(param.size,0)
  }
  return sum + param.country;
}

console.log(recursion(data, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof param.size !== 'undefined'` - здесь вы не учитываете, что каждый объект, кроме внешнего, вложен в дополнительный массив. Т.е. нужно отдельно проверять элементы массвов `param[0].size, param[1].size...`, а это можно сделать, например, в цикле:

```js
let data = getData();
console.log(recursion(data, 0));

function recursion(obj, sum) {
  if (!obj instanceof Object) return sum;
  // Если не массив, и не объект

  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    // Если наткнулись на массив,
    // к сумме прибавить результат вызова для каждого вложенного в него объекта
    let arr = obj;
    arr.forEach(innerObj => sum += recursion(innerObj, 0))
  }
 
  if (obj.country % 2 == 0) sum += obj.country;

  // Наличие массива уже учтено выше.
  // Если дошло сюда, значит находимся в объекте, у которого может быть size.
  return obj.size ? sum + recursion(obj.size, 0) : sum;
}

/***/
function getData() {
  return {
    country: 2,
    size: [{
        country: 4,
        size: [{
          country: 2,
          size: [{
            country: 1,
          }]
        }]
      },
      {
        country: 3,
        size: [{
          country: 6,
          size: [{
            country: 5,
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

Но пока массив не очень большой, можно не заморачиваться с рекурсией, потому что:

```js
let data = getData();

console.log( sum(data) );

function sum(obj) {
  let even = JSON.stringify(obj).match(/country":\d*[02468]/g);
  // \d*[02468] — \d любая цифра (digit), * от 0 до "много" раз подряд, 
  // и чтобы число заканчивалось на 0, 2, 4, 6 или 8.

  if (!even) return 0;
  
  return even.map(str => +str.match(/\d+/)[0]).reduce((a,b) => a + b);
  // Плюсик перед str - превращает полученную строку в число.
}

/***/
function getData() {
  return {
    country: 2,
    size: [{
        country: 4,
        size: [{
          country: 2,
          size: [{
            country: 1,
          }]
        }]
      },
      {
        country: 3,
        size: [{
          country: 6,
          size: [{
            country: 5,
          }]
        }]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```